# How do I know a `LazyColumn` can be navigated?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-list

How do I know a `LazyColumn` can be navigated?

For example, a list contains 100 elements, then it is a lazy column that can be scroll and we show a fab button to scroll up, but when this list contains 5 elements, the lazy column is not scrollable and the `FabButton` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lazy list layout information can be obtained from `state`, which is passed to `LazyColumn`.

In my example, I use `derivedStateOf` to prevent redundant recompositions - this will cause a recomposition only when the value actually changes. Reading `LazyColumn` state information without `derivedStateOf` or [side effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) function can cause significant performance problems.

The most basic logic in such cases is to check if the first element has been scrolled:

```kotlin
val canScrollToTop by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.run {
            isNotEmpty() && (first().index > 0 || first().offset < 0)
        }
    }
}
LazyColumn(state = state) {
   // ...
}
if (canScrollToTop) {
    // your button
}
```